# Script go get the images that do not have the @2x image

Tags: iphone

I would like to create a script that parses all my iPhone application folders and prints (exports into a file) the image names that do not have the @2x image.

Example:

Let's say we have: eaxmple.png but we dont have example@2x.png => it should print example.png since it does not have example@2x.png in it's folder.

Can you please give me good way to start, or any hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use next bash script for this task

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=`find . -name "*.png"`

for file in $FILES
do

  if [[ "$file" == *@2x.png ]]
  then
    continue
  fi

  RETINA_FILENAME=${file/\.png/@2x\.png}
  if test -e $RETINA_FILENAME;
  then
    continue
  fi

  echo $file

done
```

Comment: For the first image that is not @2x it says no such file or directory? Is there something else to add?

Comment: can you post some example for this case? I've wrote this scrip on cygwin environment, but now i've tested it on os x 10.6 and it still work.